# How to upload a file into a specific location in the Google Drive using the JS API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I'm using `googleapis` to upload different files to the Google Drive. The scenario is:

1. User provides a document and it's information through my REST API (I'm using NodeJS).
2. The REST API creates the directory that will contain the document, if it's not already exist.
3. The REST API uploads the document to that directory.

The structure of the drive is:

```
/root/documents/$type/$new_document
```

where `$type` is one of the user's provided fields and the `$new_document` is the document that was provided by the user.

The way I connect:

```
oauth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN });
drive_instance = google.drive({
  version: 'v3',
  auth: oauth2Client,
});
```

I figured how to upload the document to **root** folder of the Google Drive:

```
}
try {
    const response = await drive.files.create({
      requestBody: {
        name: file.name,
        mimeType: file.mimetype,
      },
      media: {
        mimeType: file.mimetype,
        body: file.data,
      },
    });

    console.log(response.data);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
}
```

What I'm struggling is:

1. How to create the directory `/root/documents/$type` if it's not already existing?
2. How to upload the `$new_document` to `/root/documents/$type`?

For the second question, I know that the [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) provide an option of `parents[]` that will contain all the folder IDs. but then, how can I get the folder ID of `/root/documents/$type`? Is there someway to combine the steps (like maybe `mkdir -p` for the directories or creating the directory will return the ID of the directory).

Answer (score 2):

**1. Try found folder you need via `drive.files.list()` method**

You need set filter. Example:

add `'q': "..."` in requestBody to search what you need

use `"name = 'Some Folder Name'"` to search by name

use `"mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"` to search only folders

Thus, combine via `and`:

`'q': "name = 'Some Folder Name' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"` to find all folders with name you chose

```
const folderName = 'Some Folder Name'


gapi.client.drive.files
                .list({
                    'q': "name = 'Some Folder Name' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
                    'pageSize': 1000,
                    'fields': "files(id, name, parents)"
                })
                .then((response) => {

                    const files = response.result.files;
                    if (files.length > 0) {
                      handleSearchResult(files)
                    } else {
                      createFolder()
                    }
                    console.log(total / (1024*1024*1024))
                });
```

About `handleSearchResult()` or `createFolder`:

- It maybe more than 1 file. So you can find necessary root getting `files[i].parents` . That's why I added `parents` in `'fields': "files(id, name, parents)"`. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files
- Also you can add searching rule e.g. `'parents contain "..."''`
  https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files
- If search brings 0 files result so just create folder by yourself. You can create path\directory step-by step. Create first folder in drive root and remember `id`. After that create second folder and add in requestBody `parentId` that equal first folder `id`. And etc... Btw you can use almost the same logic to search.

**2. Create folder if its necessary**

Example:

```
// name = 'Folder Name', 
// parents = ['some-parent1-id', 'some-parent2-id', ...]
function createFolder(name, parents) {
            const fileMetadata = {
                'name' : name,
                'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
                'parents': parents
            };
            gapi.client.drive.files
                .create({
                    resource: fileMetadata,
                }).then((response) => {
                    switch(response.status){
                        case 200:
                            const file = response.result;

                            console.log('Created Folder Id: ' + file.id);
                            break;
                        default:
                            console.log('Error creating the folder, '+response);
                            break;
                    }
                });
        }
```

**3. Upload file with setted `parents`**

you should add `parents = ['id-of-folder']` in `requestBody`

Read more in [Google Drive API - Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

> I hope it will help at least a bit:) Keep it up!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What is `gapi`? I'm using `googleapis`. And I import it like so: `const { google } = require('googleapis');`.

Comment: just I used another way: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js?hl=en_US . But maybe using `googleapis` looks better)

Comment: In your way just do as you did: drive.files.list() instead of mine gapi.client.drive.files.list() and etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can upload a folder inside a folder using the follow method

1. You should have the id of the folder you want to store the new folder in **(can be extracted using nodejs api or by opening the folder and looking at the characters after last / in the url)**
2. Use a special mimetype reserved for folders in google drive **( application/vnd.google-apps.folder )**

*considering your example*

```
drive.files.create({
  requestBody:{
    name:"SomeFolder",
    mimeType:"application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
  },(error,folder)=>{
    console.log(folder.data.id);
    drive.files.create:({
       requestBody:{
       name:"SomeFolderInsideAFolder",
       mimeType:"application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
       },
       parents:[folder.data.id]
    })
 })
})
```

You can even easily create a recursively uploading folder function by combining file upload and folder upload which can upload a whole folder